# Unrecognized C# syntax

Tags: c#, .net

Let's say we have:

```
class Foo
{
    public int IntPropertyInFoo { get; set; }

    public Bar BarPropertyInA { get; set; }
}

class Bar
{
    public string StringPropertyInBar { get; set; }
}
```

Then we'd like to instantiate `Foo` with an object initializer:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo = new Foo
    {
        IntPropertyInFoo = 123,
        BarPropertyInA = // Ommiting new and type name - why does it compile?
        {
            StringPropertyInBar = "something"
        }
    };
}
```

The syntax of initializing `BarPropertyInA` baffles me, because the code compiles without warnings and, when run, throws `NullReferenceException`. I don't recognize that syntax, but it seems to have the same effect when used with a field, rather than a property.

Disassembling the compiled code yields this:

```
.method public hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       34 (0x22)
  .maxstack  3
  .locals init ([0] class Test.Foo foo)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  newobj     instance void Test.Foo::.ctor()
  IL_0006:  dup
  IL_0007:  ldc.i4.s   123
  IL_0009:  callvirt   instance void Test.Foo::set_IntPropertyInFoo(int32)
  IL_000e:  nop
  IL_000f:  dup
  IL_0010:  callvirt   instance class Test.Bar Test.Foo::get_BarPropertyInA()
  IL_0015:  ldstr      "something"
  IL_001a:  callvirt   instance void Test.Bar::set_StringPropertyInBar(string)
  IL_001f:  nop
  IL_0020:  stloc.0
  IL_0021:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

Which looks like:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var foo = new Foo
    {
        IntPropertyInFoo = 123
    };

    foo.BarPropertyInA.StringPropertyInBar = "something";
}
```

So is this supposed to be some syntactic sugar for initializing property's/field's members, provided that the property/field is initialized in the constructor?

Comment: That's why I always new up other classes and lists in my class constructor.

Comment: If you had a constructor for `Foo` that sets `BarPropertyInA` to a new `Bar` then this allows you to just set the `StringPropertyInBar` property.  They went with this instead of something like `BarPropertyInA.StringPropertyInBar = "something"`

Comment: I beleive the same is done with array constructors and the likes. .Net will imply best constructor based on the context of instantiatin

Comment: It seems the answer is yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a sort of shorthand for initializing properties that start as empty rather than null. The .net collection properties are a good example of this.

```
var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()
{
    Parameters = 
    {
        new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@p1", Value = "SomValue"}
    },
    CommandText = "select 1 from Table1 where Value = @p1"
};
```

It also allows you to initialize the values of read-only properties.

```
//compiles and works
var message = new MailMessage { To = { "test@stackoverflow.com" } };

message = new MailMessage
{
    // won't compile: To is read-only
    To = new MailAddressCollection { "test@stackoverflow.com" },
};
```

Borrowed pretty much verbatim from this article:
http://www.codeducky.org/even-concise-c-object-initializers/

> New-less initializer syntax allows you to make your code a bit more concise and to use initialization syntax for configuring read-only properties. Indeed, since most base class library and popular .NET package classes follow the empty over null pattern for collection properties, you can nearly always take advantage of new-less syntax for them. Finally, using new-less initialization also means that you benefit from leaving in place any defaults an object was initialized with.